# display picture as thumbnail in windows media player in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am working on winforms using c# where the user will add a path of video and upload a picture that should be displayed as thumbnail of video. I am using windows media player for video displaying. How can I display that uploaded picture as thumbnail?
I do not want the extracted frame of video rather I want on thumbnail the picture that the user uploaded by himself in a picture box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Media Player Control (winforms) - capture current frame as bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640675/windows-media-player-control-winforms-capture-current-frame-as-bitmap)

Comment: @Andy I do not want the extracted frame of video rather I want on thumbnail the picture that the user uploaded by himself in a picture box.

Comment: @Little Start, does this solve your problem?https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2fd3230-6fe2-455e-9b33-9a203fb8edee/c-windows-form-project-displaying-picture-and-handling-event-video?forum=winforms